# Extract line-by-line info from multi-line cells in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets

A Google Sheet has multi-line information in its cells, e.g. address.
[image]

Each address can have a different number of lines, but we know:
1st line is always the name
Penultimate line is always the post code and city
Last line is always the country

And we are trying to split the address into 4 columns:
Name
Street address (i.e. the address left over after extracting name, post code & city, country)
Post code and city
Country
So col B (name) reads first line `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,”(\w.*)”)`

Of course, I can figure out how many lines there are in each cell by counting next line character
`=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),””))`
If the formula returns 6, then there are 7 lines
How do we get columns C (street address), D (postcode and city) and E (country) formulaically?

I mean, sure, I can get country for this cell with
`=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,”(\n.*){6}”)` 
but I can’t copy the formula over….the 6 above is manual input, which defeats the purpose. Since this is regex, it obviously can’t take cell references instead of 6, e.g.

`=REGEXEXTRACT(Amazon!B4,”(\n.*){F1}”)`
(if for example, I stored in column F the number of next line characters in column A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA({REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(.*)\n"), 
 REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\n(.*)$", ), "\n(.*)$", ), "^(.*)\n", ), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "\n(.*)$", ), "(.*)$"), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(.*)$")}))
```

[image]